# Windows XP doesn't recognize devices on Mac

Tags: mac, bootcamp, windows, driver

I installed a Windows XP on an iMac beside Mac OS X. When i start Windows XP it appears that it doesn't recognize devices like network card, sound card and video card as well as other devices. It cannot connect to the internet, so i am trying to download the device drivers from the Mac OS.

Is there any way to do that, any links where can I download the drivers necessary for Windows XP to recognize all devices?

Comment: Windows XP has not been supported under Boot Camp for several years now on recent hardware so depending on what Apple Hardware and version of (Mac) OS X you're running Windows XP may not be supported and therefore the directions from Sébastien Fulmer may/may not be applicable.  If not the Windows XP Boot Camp Drivers might have to be downloaded directly from Apple's website under Downloads. That said next time you ask a question include your Apple Hardware information and what version of OS X you're running as it can make a difference in the answer to some questions.  Especially like this.

Comment: With "beside OS X" you mean Bootcamp? Which OS X version are you running?

Comment: Thanks @user3439894
My Apple hardware is an iMac (27-inch, Mid 2011),  and the version of (Mac) is OS X Lion 10.7. 
Actually it is not Bootcamp, sorry i didn't mentioned that later, I am running each OS on a different partition, I tried Bootcamp but it doesn't work, I think I might try Windows 7 anyway.

Comment: @Wassim Ayoub, According to [System requirements to install Windows on your Mac using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204048) the **iMac (27-inch, Mid 2011)** _does not support Windows XP_.  Also since Windows XP is no longer supported with Security Updates for Consumer Users I'd strongly advise against even using it!  Windows 7 is a better choice however it will probably be difficult to find a legitimate retail version and at a reasonable price.

Comment: Thanks @user3439894 i really appreciate!!
your comments are very helpful

Answer (score 3):

Plug in a USB drive that is formatted with FAT while on Mac OS and run Bootcamp Utility, then select the download Windows drivers option. Reboot back into Windows and run Bootcamp.exe/Setup.exe either from AutoPlay or manually.

Comment: You have to patch stock XP in order to read exFAT